# 7z “is not supported archive” while updating an archive

Tags: linux, backup, incremental-backup, compression

```
7za u -pPasswored -mhe=on -r -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m '-x!temp' filename.7z  /home/software
```

While updating the archive we are getting this error:

> Error: XXXXXXX.7z is not supported archive
>
> System error:
>   Operation not permitted

Comment: Are you using this on Windows or some Linux OS ?

Comment: What does `7za t filename.7z` say ?

Comment: Maybe the file.7z is not really a .7z

Answer (score 1):

When `filename.7z` is exist and not a valid 7-zip file, you will get this error.

Case 1: `filename.7z` is a empty file.

```
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chenyang chenyang  0 Jun 11 23:19 empty.7z
$ 7za a empty.7z /tmp/test2/*
Error: empty.7z is not supported archive
```

Case 2: `filename.7z` is a text file (not empty).

```
$ cat text.7z
NOT_VALID
$ 7za a text.7z /tmp/test2/*
Error: text.7z is not supported archive
```